# Can I pass table-valued parameters agnostically?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have invested some effort in using ADO.NET to communicate with the back-end SQL Server in an agnostic manner.  I write code to use IDbConnection, IDbCommand, IDataReader, not concrete types.  This has worked pretty well for me. I can write code like:

```
using (IDbConnection connection = Connector.Connection)
using (IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    ...
    command.AddParameter("@id", id);
    using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {...}
    ....
}
```

The magic of associating the IDbConnection to a SqlConnection is abstracted away to the factory-like thing I call a Connector here.

We would like to use a table-valued parameter as an argument to a stored procedure.  I don't see any examples of using the SQL table-valued parameter that don't use a SqlConnection, a SqlCommand, a SqlParamater, and a SqlDataType.  Is there a way I can pass a table-valued parameter through ADO.NET without resorting to a concrete SQL ADO implementation?

Comment: Just curious, have you considered passing your parameters in as serialized JSON and then de-serializing it in your SQL procedure? not sure if that would even possibly help :sweatsmile:

Comment: That is a good idea about an approach.  Too bad if I can't use the nifty native feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can pass a table-valued parameter through ADO.NET without resorting to a concrete SQL ADO implementation

No.

You'll have to downcast to SqlParameter when doing SQL Server-specific stuff, like Table-Valued Parameters. eg

```
var param = command.AddParameter("@table", dt);
var sqlParam = (SqlParameter) param;
sqlParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;  
sqlParam.TypeName = "dbo.CategoryTableType";
```

Of course you could use Reflection, but that would just be a waste of time.

Comment: Is it only needed for TypeName? Are DbParameter.DbType and SqlDbType linked?

Comment: `DbParameter.DbType` accepts an enumeration of "standard" DbTypes that are mapped to Sql Server types by the driver.  But not all SQL Server types have a corresponding DbType.